# Dynamically render components in content Drawer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a menu where users can select an item and it will open a drawer that will display the selected item component.

I am re-using the same Drawer, would this be the correct way to dynamically render components based on type?

What improvements or changes can I make in terms of performance (thinking of lazy loading content components) or any cleanup I need to make when it's closed?

```
const Drawer = ({ type, isOpen }) => {
    let contentType;
    switch (type) {
    case "Albums":
      contentType = <Album />;
      break;
    case "Songs":
      contentType = <Songs />;
      break;
    default:
      contentType = null;
      break;
  }
    return(
       <div open={isOpen}>
         {contentType}
       </div> 
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just map the type to its component using a dict:

```
const Drawer = ({ type, isOpen }) => {
  return <div open={isOpen}>{DRAWER_COMPONENT[type]}</div>;
};

const DRAWER_COMPONENT = {
  Albums: <Album />,
  Songs: <Songs />,
};
```